# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I am getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array." error when using this code:

```
Dim RandomA As String = "aAÀàÁâÄäÅåĀāĂăĄąǞǟǺǻÃãÄ"
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("a", RandomA((Int(Rnd() * RandomA.Count)) - 1))
```

I fail to see how the (random) index can be out of bounds?

Comment: Ben, please don't put tags like "(VB.NET)" in the title. Just leave taht for the tags. Also, take a look around and see what others are using for tags. Yours were terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Int(Rnd() * RandomA.Count)` could return 0, and 0 - 1 is outside the bounds.

Comment: @Ben: Microsofts documentation of the `Rnd` function says "The Rnd function returns a value less than 1, but greater than or equal to zero."

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: try `Int(Double.Epsilon * RandomA.Count)`

Comment: It returns 0.0 as expected. Your explanation is OK. I just wanted to explain the `Rnd` function.

Answer (score 0):

it is an edge condition for sure.
the equation evaluates to -1 under certain random number conditions.